# how to skip two parent nodes of json while converting to object in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, parsing

I have a nested json whose structure is not fixed. the structure and names keep changing depending on the request parameter. but the json starts with two initial nodes "DEFAULT" which i want to skip when I convert the json to json object. How do I do that in java. I will be parsing and using this in my spring boot application.

```
{ "Default" : {
               "Default" : { 
                            "name_1" : {.....}, 
                            "name_2" : {....}
                           }
              }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a DTO that looks like this

```
class Dto {
   private static final String DEFAULT_KEY = "Default";
   private Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> data;

   public Map<String, Object> getDataWithoutDefaultNodes() {
       return data.get(DEFAULT_KEY).get(DEFAULT_KEY);
   }
}
```

Once spring boot converts above json to DTO object, just call `dto. getDataWithoutDefaultNodes()` and you will get key-value pair of JSON data without "Default" nodes.

Depending on data types of `name_1`, `name_2`, `name_n` Object could vary between primitive data types and `Map`. For example, if `name_1` is another nested JSON, `Object` will be of type `Map`.